# Is it possible to emulate a flash drive via a USB "A to A" Cable?

Tags: windows, usb, usb-storage, emulation, wii

I have a modified Nintendo Wii that can run backup game files (via external media, IE; flash drive, sd card, external HD) and an always on PC that sits right beside it with tons of storage. I'd like to just run a USB A to A between the two from a drive (or partition) on the computer that's set to emulate a flash drive/external hard drive via the USB port. Is this possible?

Comment: @David Schwartz
So in other posts and on the one you linked, there are users referencing the file transfer type USB cables and the special drivers and commands associated with them. I wonder if there's not a way to take advantage of this for the purposes I'm seeking.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a PC with a device USB port. I've never seen them on laptops or desktops, only on tablets or phones. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120512/9851) for more information.